# php function change html content from function to return them instead of displaying them

Tags: function, return

I have a function

```
myfunc(){

   ?>
   <h1>Title</h1>
   <div class="container">
       <?php if (condition): ?>
           <div class="something">more data</div>
       <?php endif; ?>
   </div>
   <?php

}
```

this function has way more HTML content combined with php if statements inside

Now, i want to store that html content into a variable so i can use it later... now it will simply display the content of the function right away which is not what i want

Comment: look into php output buffering

Comment: what syntax is this: `if (condition):`?

Comment: @Ejay will check that, thanks
@WebnetMobile it could be `if (1==1):` its just to show that there are if conditionals inside the html content of the function

Comment: Put the html code into a string variable and return that variable before the method's closing bracket.

Comment: @AlexCostea That would require quite some time to rewrite the whole code into a string variable since its quite big... Thats my only hope now but i do hope that there could be a better solution out there

Comment: Ejay was right and you can use output buffering then and buffer the output while your method runs and stores the output and then copy it into a variable http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php. Check out ob_start().

Answer (score 0):

have a look into php heredoc  and nowdoc

it may help

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc